# SQLAlchemy 2.0 mock is inserting data

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest-mock

I am trying to test a SQLAlchemy 2.0 repository and I am getting the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "professions_name_key"

So, although I am mocking the test, it inserts data into the database. What should I do to the test not insert data into the database?

I am using pytest-mock.

Here is the SQLAlchemy model

```
# File src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model.py
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from src.infra.db_models.db_base import Base


class ProfessionsDBModel(Base):
    """ Defines the professions database model.
    """

    __tablename__ = "professions"

    profession_id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200), nullable=False)
```

Here is the repository:

```
# File src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.py

from typing import Dict, Optional
import copy
import uuid
from src.domain.entities.profession import Profession
from src.interactor.interfaces.repositories.profession_repository \
    import ProfessionRepositoryInterface
from src.domain.value_objects import ProfessionId
from src.infra.db_models.db_base import Session
from src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model import ProfessionsDBModel


class ProfessionPostgresqlRepository(ProfessionRepositoryInterface):
    """ Postgresql Repository for Profession
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._data: Dict[ProfessionId, Profession] = {}

    def __db_to_entity(self, db_row: ProfessionsDBModel) -> Optional[Profession]:
        return Profession(
            profession_id=db_row.profession_id,
            name=db_row.name,
            description=db_row.description
        )

    def create(self, name: str, description: str) -> Optional[Profession]:
        session = Session()
        profession_id=uuid.uuid4()
        profession = ProfessionsDBModel(
            profession_id=profession_id,
            name=name,
            description=description
        )
        session.add(profession)
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(profession)
        if profession is not None:
            return self.__db_to_entity(profession)
        return None
```

Here is the test:

```
import uuid
import pytest
from src.infra.db_models.db_base import Session
from src.domain.entities.profession import Profession
from src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model import ProfessionsDBModel
from .profession_postgresql_repository import ProfessionPostgresqlRepository
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_profession_postgresql_repository(mocker, fixture_profession_developer):
    
    
    mocker.patch(
        'uuid.uuid4',
        return_value=fixture_profession_developer["profession_id"]
    )
    professions_db_model_mock = mocker.patch(
        'src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model.ProfessionsDBModel')
    session_add_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "add"
    )
    session_commit_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "commit"
    )
    session_refresh_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "refresh"
    )

    repository = ProfessionPostgresqlRepository()
    repository.create(
        fixture_profession_developer["name"],
        fixture_profession_developer["description"]
    )

    assert session_add_mock.add.call_once_with(professions_db_model_mock)
    assert session_commit_mock.commit.call_once_with()
    assert session_refresh_mock.refresh.call_once_with(professions_db_model_mock)
```

Comment: `.flush()` maybe but I don't think this approach will work, ie.  To mock entire session

Comment: Some people use SQLite in memory while other people rollback every transaction for every test.

Comment: @IanWilson, as I am mocking, I understand that SQLAlchemy shouldn't run and the data shouldn't be inserted. Am I not right?

Comment: How are you defining your `Session` in `src.infra.db_models.db_base`?   Are you using `sessionmaker()`?

Comment: Yes. 

Here's how I am doing:

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

I think that my error here was that I should point professions_db_model_mock  to the module of the repository like this:

professions_db_model_mock = mocker.patch(
     'src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.ProfessionsDBModel')
But I think that I still need to set what professions_db_model_mock  should return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution don't need to pass the session as parameter.
The solution was to mock the Session and not its methods separately.

As an advantage, the test is more concise now!

```
import uuid
import pytest
from src.domain.entities.profession import Profession
from src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model import ProfessionsDBModel
from .profession_postgresql_repository import ProfessionPostgresqlRepository


def test_profession_postgresql_repository(
        mocker,
        fixture_profession_developer
):

    mocker.patch(
        'uuid.uuid4',
        return_value=fixture_profession_developer["profession_id"]
    )
    professions_db_model_mock = mocker.patch(
        'src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.\
ProfessionsDBModel')
    session_mock = mocker.patch(
        'src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.Session')
    professions_db_model = ProfessionsDBModel(
        profession_id = fixture_profession_developer["profession_id"],
        name = fixture_profession_developer["name"],
        description = fixture_profession_developer["description"]
    )
    professions_db_model_mock.return_value = professions_db_model
    repository = ProfessionPostgresqlRepository()
    result = repository.create(
        fixture_profession_developer["name"],
        fixture_profession_developer["description"]
    )
    profession = Profession(
        professions_db_model_mock.return_value.profession_id,
        professions_db_model_mock.return_value.name,
        professions_db_model_mock.return_value.description
    )
    session_mock.add.assert_called_once_with(professions_db_model_mock())
    session_mock.commit.assert_called_once_with()
    session_mock.refresh.assert_called_once_with(professions_db_model_mock())
    assert result == profession
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution passing the session as a parameter to the repository class. I used MagicMock to mock the session.

```
""" Module for ProfessionPostgresqlRepository
"""


from typing import Dict, Optional
import copy
import uuid
from src.domain.entities.profession import Profession
from src.interactor.interfaces.repositories.profession_repository \
    import ProfessionRepositoryInterface
from src.domain.value_objects import ProfessionId
from src.infra.db_models.db_base import Session
from src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model import ProfessionsDBModel


class ProfessionPostgresqlRepository(ProfessionRepositoryInterface):
    """ Postgresql Repository for Profession
    """
    def __init__(self, session) -> None:
        self.__session = session
        self.__data: Dict[ProfessionId, Profession] = {}

    def __db_to_entity(self, db_row: ProfessionsDBModel) -> Optional[Profession]:
        return Profession(
            profession_id=db_row.profession_id,
            name=db_row.name,
            description=db_row.description
        )

    def create(self, name: str, description: str) -> Optional[Profession]:
        profession_id=uuid.uuid4()
        profession = ProfessionsDBModel(
            profession_id=profession_id,
            name=name,
            description=description
        )
        self.__session.add(profession)
        self.__session.commit()
        self.__session.refresh(profession)
        if profession is not None:
            return self.__db_to_entity(profession)
        return None
```

Here is the test:

```
import uuid
import pytest
from src.infra.db_models.db_base import Session
from src.domain.entities.profession import Profession
from src.infra.db_models.profession_db_model import ProfessionsDBModel
from .profession_postgresql_repository import ProfessionPostgresqlRepository
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_profession_postgresql_repository(mocker, fixture_profession_developer):
    
    session = mocker.MagicMock()
    mocker.patch(
        'src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.uuid.uuid4',
        return_value=fixture_profession_developer["profession_id"]
    )
    profession = ProfessionsDBModel(
        profession_id=fixture_profession_developer["profession_id"],
        name=fixture_profession_developer["name"],
        description=fixture_profession_developer["description"]
    )
    professions_db_model_mock = mocker.patch(
        'src.infra.repositories.profession_postgresql_repository.ProfessionsDBModel')
    professions_db_model_mock.return_value = profession
    session_add_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "add"
    )
    session_commit_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "commit"
    )
    session_refresh_mock = mocker.patch.object(
        Session,
        "refresh"
    )

    repository = ProfessionPostgresqlRepository(session)
    repository.create(
        fixture_profession_developer["name"],
        fixture_profession_developer["description"]
    )

    assert session_add_mock.add.call_once_with(professions_db_model_mock)
    assert session_commit_mock.commit.call_once_with()
    assert session_refresh_mock.refresh.call_once_with(professions_db_model_mock)
```